# Making a footnote in Abstract of a paper under the document class "amsart"?

Tags: footnotes, abstract, amsart

The search attempts seemed to only show how to make a footnote work as usual in Abstract if the document class is a usual one. However, for the class amsart it seems that none of the methods works.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\title{Right1}
\begin{abstract}
Right2\footnote{right2}
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\section{Intro}
Right3\footnote{right3}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A kludge that should teach you not to footnote abstracts. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\title{Right1}
\begin{abstract}
Right2\footnotemark
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\stepcounter{footnote}
\footnotetext{right2}

\section{Intro}
Right3\footnote{right3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I reduced the text height in order to make a smaller picture.